# Copy UserForm data to the next empty row inside PowerPoint Chart

Tags: vba, userform, powerpoint

I created a UserForm, with the help of many, within PowerPoint to assist with consistent embedded chart data entries.  From what I have learned I will never do this again because addtional code that is needed to traverse through the PowerPoint to get to the correct location for the desired updates.  No matter, I would like to finish the final objective of getting data from the UserForm into the first empty row.  I have code but there is an error that is preventing the data to unload.  The code I have is below.  Any help in identifying the glitch is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CPDataAdd_Click()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As shape
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim xlWB As Object

        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                    If shp.Type = msoChart Then
                        If shp.Name = "DVchart" Then
                            Set xlWB = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
            Next
            If Not xlWB Is Nothing Then Exit For
        Next

Set shp = sld.Shapes("DVchart")
Set xlWB = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook

Dim LastRow As Long

    With xlWB.Sheets(1)

        LastRow = .Range("AI" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1

        .Range("AI" & LastRow).Value = CPDate.Text
        .Range("BI" & LastRow).Value = CPCompleteN.Text
        .Range("CI" & LastRow).Value = CPPassN.Text
        .Range("DI" & LastRow).Value = CPFailN.Text
        .Range("EI" & LastRow).Value = CPNotN.Text

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It will help if you mention what line the error occurs on and the *exact* text of the error message.

Comment: Thanks Steve,  The line with the error is 'LastRow = .Range("AI" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1'.  The returned error is a Compile Error Variable Undefined and is in reference to (xlup).

Comment: xlup is an Excel constant; PowerPoint doesn't know anything about it, so you'll want to add "Const xlup as Long = -4162" (sans quote marks) to the top of the module containing your code.

Comment: I included the constant in the top of the module and all functionality works as hoped.  Thanks Steve R.